# How can I crop Image on-the-fly using FREE API (or a single line of code)?

Tags: image, frontend, crop, on-the-fly

I am figuring out a way to crop the images in the database on-the-fly for using it at various solts, positions and different pages on my web site. Is there a solution to do it seamlessly?

I tried using various online editors but couldn't arrive to a powerful API.

Comment: *"On-the-fly"* between what database and what other destination/source, via what route (Javascript/Python something else) on what platform? Thank you.

Comment: I am using Mongo DB and Amazon S3 to store my multimedia files and the asset URLs and the destination is the final rendering of the Website using ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

You can use Front.Space or Cloudinary to optimise the Images and Videos on-the-fly using their URL based API. The syntax is pretty simple and does not require you to switch your storage DB.